# PHPMailer: error Policy Rejection

Tags: php, phpmailer, large-data

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($recipients as $email => $name) {

    $mail->AddBCC($email, $name); 
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        $send = 0;
    } else {
        $send = 1;
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO `newsletter_send`(`email`, `id_newsletter`, `date`, `send`) VALUES ('$email',$id_newsletter, NOW(),$send) ";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($query) or die('error');
    $stmt->execute();
    $mail->clearAllRecipients(); 
    $mail->ClearAddresses();

    if (($i % 300) == 0) {
        sleep(5);
    }

    $i++;
}
```

For some users the email is not sent .. I tried to send the email individually and I get the following error

> SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: c***@**.it: : Sender address rejected: Policy Rejection- Quota Exceeded.

Comment: Which SMTP server you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite incomplete, more detail would help. Sending messages individually using BCC does not make any sense. There's no reason to BCC because each message only has one recipient, so there's nobody to hide addresses from.

Not all email address will work all the time. Expect errors and deal with them. For temporary delivery failures, you should retry - but don't do this from PHP, get your mail server to do it as it will do a better job.